# Minimum Developers to Manager ratio

Tags: agile, human-resources, workload

We have 3 full time developers but we would like to recruit up to 5 in the future.

We have two priority projects, both with fully estimated backlogs. The team also handles some additional maintenance issues. Backlog priorities have been set and any incoming tasks are screening by one of the Directors. Do you think theres's value getting in a full time project manager at this stage, or do you think one of the lead developers should transition into this role?

Comment: Is a _manager_ a must? No. Is _management_ a must? Yes. With that said, there's way too many criteria to find a canonical answer for your question, so I'm afraid that, as it stands, it may be considered off-topic. I'd suggest to rephrase is so that you ask for more concrete answers, such as what aspects to observe to decide whether a team needs a dedicated manager or not.

Comment: There is not enough detail to offer canonical answers to your question. *Why* do you need X managers per Y developers in your environment? What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a proper span of control. There are a lot of theories on this subject and a few variables you need to consider as you are designing your organization. Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_of_control) and then research some of the citations at the bottom.

I would suggest there is no single right answer as those variables would dictate different designs. You're essentially dealing with a ton of moving pros, cons, and risks of various span of control designs.